# Broken Gnome Shell

Tags: apt, dpkg, gnome-shell, pop-os

I was trying to update some package in my computer but it seems now I can't even run simple `sudo apt install` command.

```
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gnome-shell : Depends: gnome-shell-common (= 42.1-0ubuntu0.1pop1~1654265234~22.04~d8fe566) but 42.2-0ubuntu0.2pop1~1656366363~22.04~47f8ae4 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

When I run `sudo apt --fix-broken install` I get the following error (even with -f flag)

```
dpkg: error processing package gnome-shell-common (--configure):
 installed gnome-shell-common package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 gnome-shell-common
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Is there anyway to fix this without needing to reinstall the OS?